# What is the universal way to open a specified PDF chapter?

Tags: c#, pdf, browser, acrobat

I want to open a pdf file programmatically at a specific chapter in Windows (with C#, but I think, this does not matter).

For Acrobat (and other standalone viewers), the following works:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Temp\\Test.pdf", "/A \"nameddest=introduction\"");
```

For Firefox (and other browsers), the following URL works, if called directly in the browser:

```
file:///C:/Temp/Test.pdf#nameddest=introduction
```

However, if Firefox is the default pdf viewer, the Acrobat command does not work and the following does also not work (it opens the pdf file, but not the specified chapter):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"file:///C:/Temp/Test.pdf#nameddest=introduction");
```

Is there some universal way to achieve the desired result? Both seem to follow a similar syntax, but I did not found a way without knowing, which pdf viewer the user is using.

Comment: It would be fine with me, if one way would at least work for both Acrobat and Browsers. But thank you for the hint of the alternative syntax, I’ll give it a try.

Comment: The `-named-dest "blah"` syntax does not work at all with my acrobat version.